# Initialization of VueJS 2 with in component not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-resource

I have a AddUser component which is like this:

```
    <script>
// import {countriesUrl, citiesUrl} from './../config'
// import axios from 'axios'
// import swal from 'sweetalert'
import Vue from 'vue'

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      currentstep: 1,
      steps: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: 'Position',
          icon_class: 'fa fa-map-marker'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: 'Category',
          icon_class: 'fa fa-folder-open'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          title: 'Send',
          icon_class: 'fa fa-paper-plane'
        }
      ]
    },

    methods: {
      stepChanged (step) {
        this.currentstep = step
      }
    }
  })
})

Vue.component('step-navigation-step', {
  template: '#step-navigation-step-template',
  props: ['step', 'currentstep'],
  computed: {
    indicatorclass () {
      return {
        active: this.step.id === this.currentstep,
        complete: this.currentstep > this.step.id
      }
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('step-navigation', {
  template: '#step-navigation-template',
  props: ['steps', 'currentstep']
})

Vue.component('step', {
  template: '#step-template',
  props: ['step', 'stepcount', 'currentstep'],

  computed: {
    active () {
      return this.step.id === this.currentstep
    },

    firststep () {
      return this.currentstep === 1
    },

    laststep () {
      return this.currentstep === this.stepcount
    },

    stepWrapperClass () {
      return {
        active: this.active
      }
    }
  },

  data: {
    currentstep: 1,
    steps: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Position',
        icon_class: 'fa fa-map-marker'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Category',
        icon_class: 'fa fa-folder-open'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Send',
        icon_class: 'fa fa-paper-plane'
      }
    ]
  },

  methods: {
    nextStep () {
      this.$emit('step-change', this.currentstep + 1)
    },

    lastStep () {
      this.$emit('step-change', this.currentstep - 1)
    }
  }
})
</script>

<template>

    <div class="wrapper" id="add-consignee-wrapper">

        <step-navigation :steps="steps" :currentstep="currentstep">
        </step-navigation>

        <div v-if="currentstep == 1">
            <h1>Step 1</h1>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div v-if="currentstep == 2">
            <h1>Step 2</h1>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleSelect1">Example select</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div v-if="currentstep == 3">
            <h1>Step 3</h1>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleTextarea">Example textarea</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" rows="4"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleInputFile" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
                <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">This is some placeholder block-level help text for the above input. It's a bit lighter and easily wraps to a new line.</small>
            </div>
        </div>

        <step v-for="step in steps" :currentstep="currentstep" :key="step.id" :step="step" :stepcount="steps.length" @step-change="stepChanged">
        </step>

        <script type="x-template" id="step-navigation-template">
            <ol class="step-indicator">
                <li v-for="step in steps" is="step-navigation-step" :key="step.id" :step="step" :currentstep="currentstep">
                </li>
            </ol>
        </script>

        <script type="x-template" id="step-navigation-step-template">
            <li :class="indicatorclass">
                <div class="step"><i :class="step.icon_class"></i></div>
                <div class="caption hidden-xs hidden-sm">Step <span v-text="step.id"></span>: <span v-text="step.title"></span></div>
            </li>
        </script>

        <script type="x-template" id="step-template">
            <div class="step-wrapper" :class="stepWrapperClass">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="lastStep" :disabled="firststep">
                    Back
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="nextStep" :disabled="laststep">
                    Next
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </div>
        </script>
    </div><!-- Consignee wrapper div -->

</template>

<style lang="scss">
  $wizard-color-neutral: #ccc !default;
$wizard-color-active: #4183D7 !default;
$wizard-color-complete: #87D37C !default;
$wizard-step-width-height: 64px !default;
$wizard-step-font-size: 24px !default;


body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.container {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.step-wrapper {
    padding: 20px 0;
    display: none;

    &.active {
        display: block;
    }
}



.step-indicator {
    border-collapse: separate;
    display: table;
    margin-left: 0px;
    position: relative;
    table-layout: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-top: 20px;

    li {
        display: table-cell;
        position: relative;
        float: none;
        padding: 0;
        width: 1%;

        &:after {
            background-color: $wizard-color-neutral;
            content: "";
            display: block;
            height: 1px;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            top: $wizard-step-width-height/2;
        }

        &:after {
            left: 50%;
        }

        &:last-child {
            &:after {
                display: none;
            }
        }

        &.active {
            .step {
                border-color: $wizard-color-active;
                color: $wizard-color-active;
            }

            .caption {
                color: $wizard-color-active;
            }
        }

        &.complete {
            &:after {
                background-color: $wizard-color-complete;
            }

            .step {
                border-color: $wizard-color-complete;
                color: $wizard-color-complete;
            }

            .caption {
                color: $wizard-color-complete;
            }
        }
    }

    .step {
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 1px solid $wizard-color-neutral;
        color: $wizard-color-neutral;
        font-size: $wizard-step-font-size;
        height: $wizard-step-width-height;
        line-height: $wizard-step-width-height;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        width: $wizard-step-width-height;
        z-index: 1;

        &:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }

    .caption {
        color: $wizard-color-neutral;
        padding: 11px 16px;
    }
}
</style>
```

When I am trying to load Vue component inside this file it is showing this error: "Do not use 'new' for side effects". I believe it is because I have already initialized vue in main.js.

Now, whenever I am loading the data attribute through export module I am getting this error: `The "data" option should be a function that returns a per-instance value in component definitions.`. `It is also saying property/method "steps" not found. Cannot find element: #step-navigation-template`

Can anyone please help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: Do you using Node + Webpack and code you provided is in *.Vue component?

Comment: @WaldemarIce yes we are using Node + Webpack and code is in vue

Comment: I'm not a view expert by any means but this looks very confusing.  You're putting all of this into a single .vue file -- with multiple components but only one `<script>` tag and one `<template>` tag?  Is that even supported?  And why are you re-instantiating Vue inside a component?  Sounds like a chicken-and-egg problem.

Comment: "Do not use 'new' for side effects - this is linter warning message, not vue https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-new

The "data" option should be a function that returns a per-instance value in component definitions. 
"The "data" option should be a function that returns a per-instance value in component definitions." - this is vue warning, additional information you can find here https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Data
You should use separate vue file for each component or just put template inside template property as a string.

Comment: You are not assigning the value of the new Vue(...) statement to anything.  change it to var vm = new Vue({